# XNA Game Studio 4.0 transfer it to Monogame, is this possible? Thanks

Tags: xna, monogame

I have made a game in XNA Game Studio 4.0 and been asked to transfer it to Monogame so that it runs in Monogame, is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - yes, it is possible but requires some work.  XNA Game Studio 4.0 is a plugin for Visual Studio, but that doesn't matter as much as the fact that the game uses the XNA .dlls, and that it's compiled against the PC platform which impacts things like file IO, reflection, and a few other subtleties.

You'll be able to re-use much of your code, but some stuff will definitely change.  To start you'll want to get a simple MonoGame project running, then work on bringing the code over.